# Classic ASP - ServerXMLHTTP NT Authentication

Tags: authentication, asp-classic, serverxmlhttp

So I have the following code which I want to use in order to download images and save them.

```
<%
function SaveFileFromUrl(Url, FileName)
    dim objXMLHTTP, objADOStream, objFSO

    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")

    objXMLHTTP.open "GET", Url, false
    objXMLHTTP.send()

    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 OR objXMLHTTP.Status = 304 Then 
        Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        objADOStream.Open
        objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

        objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
        objADOStream.Position = 0 'Set the stream position to the start

        Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If objFSO.Fileexists(FileName) Then objFSO.DeleteFile FileName
        Set objFSO = Nothing

        objADOStream.SaveToFile FileName
        objADOStream.Close
        Set objADOStream = Nothing

        SaveFileFromUrl = objXMLHTTP.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")
    else
        SaveFileFromUrl = ""
    End if
    response.write objXMLHTTP.Status
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
end function
%>
```

When I run this on images from the web, it works fine. However when trying to use it on intranet images that need NT authentication, I get a 401 error back by using `response.write objXMLHTTP.Status`

So my somewhat obvious question is - how do I go about this in the script without taking off NT authentication?

**HOWEVER**

It may also be due to the fact that the images do not have an extension. They are in the form `http://domain/thumbs/image1` rather than `http://domain/thumbs/image1.png`

Either way, I can't get it to work!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
objXMLHTTP.open(bstrMethod, bstrUrl, bAsync, bstrUser, bstrPassword);
```